# How can I forward Exchange emails to the Internet?

Tags: exchange

I have an Exchange 2016 server set and configured on a VM. The FQDN for the Send Connector is set as, '*'. This is so emails are Internet routable. Now, I need to have a forwarder in the DNS to forward the emails to the Internet. Given, the IPv4 network being used, 172.16.91.93's network is a lab network and the Windows Server 2016 VM has access to the Internet, how can this be done? One of the forwarders is 8.8.8.8. A LAN to Internet connection for email transfer is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to send mail to external Internet mail address from your Exchange mailbox?

If yes, I noticed you have created a send connector, then ensure your DNS server could resolve MX records from internet, a DNS forward in on-premise DNS server is an option as you said. 
For example: send mail to user@a.com, run “nslookup -type=mx a.com” in CMD on Exchange server, check if it can return any server information, Exchange server will try to deliver the mail to the returned server if existing.